# Java: StackOverflowError for FileSystem.getDefaultUri

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to create the instance of Distributed FS:

```
  Configuration config = new Configuration();
  config.set("fs.defaultFS", "/");
  FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("/"), config);
```

Applicaion run at distribited cluster.
But receive the following error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.net.URI.access$300(URI.java:464)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.scan(URI.java:2995)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3018)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3104)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3062)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getDefaultUri(FileSystem.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:172)
```

Also I tried to configured instanse so:

```
 FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(config);
```

But with the same result.

I have found the ticket for familiar problem: [HADOOP-13792](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13792)
The ticket is resolved for version 2.7.2.

And my version is 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the correct schema and authority in the

```
config.set("fs.defaultFS", "/");
```

Such as `file:///` or `hdfs://namenode:port/`

and change like this

```
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(config);
```